# MVC 4 model field custom authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

We are creating an MVC 4 application that requires the user to be authorized to view and/or interact with certain model fields based on his/hers role membership.

For example if the model has a field SSN, the user should be allowed to view this field only if he/she is a member of the admin role. Once displayed the user should be able to modify it only if member of the profile_admin role.  In other words, the SSN field should not be rendered if the user is not a member of the admin role and should be disabled if the user is not a member of the profile_admin role.  Which roles have the permissions should be  controlled by the site admin via the admin UI.

One possible solution is to wrap the SSN field in a partial view and then handle the rendering in our custom view engine. However, this method will require every field that we want to control to be in a partial view and it would require code change if the user wants to control another field (say HireDate)

We were hoping that we could achieve this by using a custom attributes in the metadata class like so:

```
[CustomFieldAuthorizeAttribute]
public string SSN { get; set; }
```

We would keep the authorization information for each field in the database like so:

```
FieldName       RoleId      AllowView      AllowEdit
SSN             1           True           False
```

When the attribute executes it will check the role membership of the currently logged user and will determine the permissions to view and edit for this field and then it will inject the appropriate html attributes like class="hidden" or disabled="disabled".

This way if the user wants to add authorization for another field, all we need to do is create a record in the database for this field.  The custom attribute will pick it up from there.

Is it possible to achieve such functionality

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you that are facing this situation, I used the concept described in [this article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=687) to create the necessary functionality. With a little tweaking, the solution worked exactly as required.

Thanks.